# What exactly is a "client" in the interface segregation principle (ISP)?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

This is one of a number of things that's been bugging me for a while and for which quibbling over the correct interpretation of this has been leading me in a number of attempted coding projects to more fussing around with design, than it has with making steady forward progress, because I want to make sure I've gotten it "right".

In this case, I have a question about the "interface segregation principle" (ISP) of the five "SOLID" principles of basic object oriented design. Its "canonical" statement is this:

> Clients should not be forced to depend on methods they do not use.

However, the question here is, is what is the "client" - because this leads to very different interpretations, and also leads to a seeming dilemma when applied in practice, which is what I'd like to understand if first actually is one, and second, how to best solve it.

One interpretation of this is that it is a "single responsibility principle" for *interfaces* instead of just classes: i.e. if you have an interface `IMessageReceiver`, it better not include a `Send` method. Another possible interpretation is that it means that the *implementer* of an interface should not be required to implement empty methods, while a third interpretation is that the *caller* should not be able to *see* any more methods than it actually needs. And the thing is, I can see merit in *all three* of these interpretations, yet when you apply them all, it seems that in any suitably large project, highly counterintuitive and seemingly problematic things result. In particular, it's that third one that seems to be the rub.

For one, if something gets used in enough places, it is particularly that *last* one - the "caller" one - which generally tends to "bite" in that it results naturally in your interfaces being atomized down to single methods only. For example, consider a simple interface to a backend storage or database, which may have a `load`, `save`, and `update` method.  Some *callers* of that, though, may not want to save anything. They may just want to peek at the data. Hence to avoid violating the caller interpretation, we must split off the load method. Add a few more use cases and now it's atomized into a `IDataLoader`, `IDataSaver`, and `IDataUpdater` which all have 1 method each.

And I can't help but feel this almost seems like an anti-pattern, particularly if it happens with enough objects owing to them being used in a suitably wide variety of places. Is it? Or am I misinterpreting something here? After all, nobody makes a generic container class (like the "list", "map", etc. things in a lot of languages) with single-method interfaces to be piecemealed out to whatever it gets passed to.

Answer (score 0):

When somebody wants to develop a feature, then he/she tries to map real world object to unit where code can be put. It is done to imitate behavior.
This unit can be called class. And this class has to have just one feature. It is place where we use SRP.

E.g., if programmer maps real world object person to class `Person`.
Then this class `Person` does not have to have methods/behavior of other objects. E.g. the `Person` class does not have to have methods of Car class. This is what SRP about.

> Clients should not be forced to depend on methods they do not use.

We've created a `Person` class so far. Now we want to log all speech of person. So we need to log it. How? We can use interface `ILogging` with one method `Log`. Why does this interface have just one method?
Because [clients will only have to know about the methods that are of interest to them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).
*Here `Person` class is client of interface `ILogging`*.

**SRP** means that a class is responsible just for one feature. E.g. if you want to edit logging in Person class, then it is violation of SRP.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public void Say(string message) 
    {
        File.WriteAllText("path", message); // violation of SRP
    }
}
```

How can we avoid violation of SRP? We should create an abstraction of logging:

```
public interface ILogging
{
    void Write(string address, string content);
}
```

and use it:

```
public class PersonWithSRP
{
    private readonly ILogging _logging;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public PersonWithSRP(ILogging logging)
    {
        _logging = logging;
    }

    public void Say(string message)
    {
        _logging.Write("path", message);
    }
}


public class Logging : ILogging
{
    public void Write(string address, string content)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(address, content);
    }
}
```

By extracting logic of logging in separate class, we moved logic of logging in special, single class or place where we can edit only logic of logging on one place.

**What is about ISP?**

> nobody makes a generic container class

yeah, you are right. Interface should have only necessary methods which client class needs.

An example with HDD that uses ISP:

```
public interface IReadable
{
    string Read();
}

public interface IWriteable
{
    void Write();
}

public class HDD : IReadable, IWriteable
{
    public string Read() { }

    public void Write()  { }
}
```

By creating one interface for `Read()` and `Write()` methods, it would obligate class to implement *both* methods in class. But some classes only want to read data, others want to write data, and some to do both. So in this case it is better to create separate interfaces.

So let's look another example with *CardReader*. *CardReader* just reads data, it does not write data. So, if we inherit one interface with `Read()` and `Write()` methods, then we  would violate ISP principle. An example of violation of ISP:

```
public interface IWriteReadable
{
    string Read();
    void Write();
}

public class CardReader : IWriteReadable
{
    // this is a necessary method
    public string Read() { }

    // here we are obligating to implement unnecessary method of interface
    public void Write() { }
}
```

So by applying ISP, you only puts methods in interface that are necessary for the client class. If your class/client just wants to read data, then you need to use `IReadable` interface, not `IReadableWriteable`.

Answer (score 0):

> One interpretation of this is that it is a "single responsibility principle" for interfaces...

[Robert Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388358/in-solid-what-is-the-distinction-between-srp-and-isp-single-responsibility-pr/55073007#55073007) has addressed this question directly, and his answer is that ISP separates things that SRP does not, thus the two principles differ.

> Another possible interpretation is that it means that the implementer of an interface...

We also see in his answer that the client is the *caller* of the interface, not the implementer. I've touched on that in another answer regarding [default methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377594/interface-segregation-principle-and-default-methods-in-java-8/60497862#60497862). The implementer should be implementing exactly as many methods as the caller needs: no more, no less.

> a third interpretation is that the caller should not be able to see any more methods than it actually needs.

This is correct, and it is also correct to note that a single-method interface cannot violate the ISP. While this may result in a "lowest-common-denominator" approach where every interface is a single method, they should be highly composable in that case; i.e. implementations can select several interfaces to implement, making them highly customizable to client needs.

The database example of separating read from write is so common that is has its own pattern: [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). There are arguments both ways. Likewise, generic [collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160222/violation-of-single-responsibility-principle-in-iterator-from-java-core/33160408#33160408) may choose to avoid creating too many interfaces, which is a design counter to the ISP.

I would suggest that in most applications (particularly service applications as opposed to libraries) if rigorously applying the ISP results exclusively in single-method interfaces, it indicates the clients are not cohesive and not complex. If this is an accurate description of the clients, then single-method interfaces are probably appropriate. You may also consider a different architecture such as a separate service for each client if their requirements have so little overlap.

Comment: ADD: By the way, if you want to know what I mean by "lots of little one element interfaces", it's this: https://imgur.com/q5LcKWA . I just got finished trying to refactor the codebase with this idea in mind to see where it went and that's what I got. That's what the relevant part looks like where those interfaces are involved. It's meant to connect a user interface layer to a logic layer, and you can see there are methods that even work on a single X and Y coordinate - that's because some higher up event handlers work on those axes independently. Is that really right?

Comment: It's critical to note that single-method interfaces do _not_ necessarily imply single-method implementations. A client may see an abstraction of a single coordinate, but the implementation may handle any number of coordinates and expose different interfaces for different combinations to different clients. The ISP increases the number of interfaces; it does not necessarily increase the number of implementations at all.