# Interface Segregation - avoid typecasting

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

I am developing a simple card game, as part of a personal project. The game has a few rules, for example:

- A card can be either action, item, or champion
- A player can play a card on their "playing field"
- Playing an action or item immediately actives their effect
- Champions enter the "playing field" "untapped", and they need to get "tapped" to activate their ability
- At end of turn, actions and items are discarded, while champions remain in play, untapped.
- A player can attack either the opponent directly, or their champions in play.

A simplistic design for this would be:

```
interface Card {}

class AbstractCard implements Card {}

class ActionCard extends AbstractCard {}

class ItemCard extends AbstractCard {}

class ChampionCard extends AbstractCard {}

class PlayingField {


  public Collection<Card> getPlayedCards() {}
}

class Player {

  private final PlayingField playingField;

  public Collection<Card> getPlayedCards() {
    return playingField.getPlayedCards();
  }
}
```

Since a `Player` could play any of `ItemCard`, `ActionCard`, or `ChampionCard`, I defined the method `getPlayedCards()` to work with `Card`. Now, in order to implement the rule that says "A player can attack either the opponent directly, or their champions in play.", I quickly realised I would need to add a method `takeDamage()` to `Card`. However, cards of type `ItemCard` or `ActionCard` would never be able to be attacked, they are not valid targets. So, adding this method on `Card` would result in needless implementation in these two classes, where I would have to throw an exception, something along the lines of:

```
public void takeDamage(Combat combat) {
  throw new NotTargetableException();
}
```

I was reading more about the Integration Segregation Principle, which basically says that I should avoid adding needless methods to an interface, so as not to force classes to implement methods that would/should never be invoked. Looking at my `Card`s, `ActionCard` and `ItemCard` would never be valid targets of an attack. Furthermore, instances of these classes would not exist inside of the collection returned from `getPlayedCards()` during opponent's turn, since they are discarded. So, a better approach would be to have:

```
interface Attackable {
  void takeDamage(Combat combat);
}

class ChampionCard extends AbstractCard implements Attackable {}

class Player implements Attackable {}
```

But now comes my dilemma. Since `Card` does not have a `takeDamage` method, and `getPlayingCards()` returns instances of `Card`, I would have to type cast this into an `Attackable` to be able to attack it. In the case of a `ClassCastException`, this would have the same meaning as my previous `NotTargetableException`. The general sentiment towards type casting, though, is that it is a code smell, and an indication that there's something wrong with the code design.

So, my question is. How would I achieve Interface Segregation without type casting in this case?

Edit:

Now that I wrote the question out, one simple "workaround" for this that I could think of, would be to have a method such as:

```
class PlayingField {

  public Collection<Card> getPlayedCards() {} // same as before

  public Collection<Attackable> targetableCards() {} // new method
}
```

And then `AttackableCards` on play would be added to this collection. Would this be the "approved" approach?

Comment: related: [What exactly is a "client" in the interface segregation principle (ISP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71525818/1371329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I decided to go with the following approach:

```
class ChampionCard implements Attackable { /* snipped */ }

class Player implements Attackable {

  public Combat combatPool() { /* snipped */ }

  public void attack(Attackable attackable, Combat combat) {
    // TODO: ensure enough combat in combatPool()
    
    attackable.takeCombat(combat);
  }

  public void takeCombat(Combat combat) { /* snipped */ }
}
```

Where an instance of `Attackable` will be supplied as an argument from the UI layer of the game, instead of having to find it via `getPlayedCards()` method. Considering the overall architecture of the game, I thought it would be easier to maintain a `Collection<Attackable>` in an `Observer` (no matter the actual mechanism of propagating changes), and fetch the instance from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any issue with changing the current hierarchy this can be done in the following way.

By Keeping different abstract parents for Attackable and Non-Attackable (safe) implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Card {
    private Champion champion;
    private Item item;
    private Action action;
    ...
}
```

i.e. instead of a Champion card being a "kind of" card, a Card "has a" Champion. (Or "can have" in this case)

Then handle the stuff you can't do. Perhaps the default item.use() is a failure or you can't call if item is null.

The card is a container that may have one or more of these other types. (Also get some flexibility such as cards that contain both a champion and an action/item like an on tap effect)