# Arrays in java violates ISP?

Tags: java, solid-principles

The code below will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` in java :

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
list.add("d");
```

I'm a little confused isn't this an ISP violation ? Here class implements the `List` interface but can't implement its method `add()`

Comment: it's not a problem, i'm just interested

Comment: And an LSP violation

Comment: I thought that the solid principles are followed in most cases

Comment: related: [Violation of single responsibility principle in Iterator from Java core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33160222/1371329)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does violate the Interface Segregation Principle, like any Unmodifiable collection. The designers of the Collections API could have created separate interfaces for write and read actions but decided to keep them together.

One could argue that this list does confirm to the ISP -- it has the `add()` function -- but the thing that it does with that function is not what you expect. [EDIT, per @progman below: And the exception *can* be considered part of the interface, because it is documented.]

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/440155/unsupportedoperationexception-vs-interface-segregation) is a related discussion on Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: Progman is conflating different principles. His argument is unrelated to the ISP. Your first paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The [`List.add()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) is defined as an optional operation:

> `boolean add(E e)`
>
> Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional operation).

And further down it defines when it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

> Throws:
>
> `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the add operation is not supported by this list

So the implementation (returned by `Arrays.asList()`) is doing what is "allowed" to do based on the specification of the `java.util.List` interface.

Comment: Hm, if we can throw exception in any method we want, why then we need ISP ?

Comment: This answer explains how the `add()` method conforms to the _LSP_, but the _ISP_ has nothing to do with documentation.